# To calculate expansion work for a process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> [1 mark] To calculate the expansion work for a process,
>   1) the formula $w = -P_\mathrm{ex}(V_2 - V_1)$ always works under all conditions.
>   2) the formula $\mathrm dw = -P_\mathrm{ex}\,\mathrm dV$ can only be used for irreversible processes.
>   3) the formula $\mathrm dw = -P_\mathrm{ex}\,\mathrm dV$ always works under all conditions.
>   4) the formula $w = -nRT\ln (V_2/V_1)$ always works for any isothermal reversible process.
>   5) None of the above is applicable.

I'm torn between options 1, 3 and 4. I see those 3 all as correct. Can someone point to me which one might be right and why?

Comment: 3 and 4 are both correct.

Comment: Why is 1 not correct? Isn't it basically the integral of 3

Comment: A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable, so I typed your question in. Please consider rewriting the text from the images in the future, so that it can be of help for future visitors. Also, it would be ideal for you to add the source of this problem (textbook/local exam).

Comment: 1 is not the integral of 3 for a reversible expansion.  4 is the integral of 3 for a reversible expansion.